# Disable 2xl breakpoint for container class

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

Tailwind 2.0.1 has a `2xl` breakpoint set to `1536px`. I would like to disable this breakpoint and set the max `container` width to the `xl` breakpoint. According to the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/container#disabling-responsive-variants), I can disable all responsive variants for the `container`, but I just want to disable this single breakpoint. Instead I have tried to disable the `2xl` breakpoint by updating the Tailwind configuration as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      '2xl': '1280px'
    }
  }
}
```

This does not work, nor do I think this would be correct when I only want to target a single class and a single breakpoint.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it's just removing this breakpoint for the container class you want to specify the breakpoints you want to **keep** in the `theme.container.screens` key.

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        container: {
            screens: {
                'sm': '640px',
                'md': '768px',
                'lg': '1024px',
                'xl': '1280px',
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you're using the same breakpoints as the main theme and you'd prefer not to specify the same breakpoints again, you can get them using the default theme.

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

let containerScreens = Object.assign({}, defaultTheme.screens)

// Delete the 2xl breakpoint from the object
delete containerScreens['2xl']

module.exports = {
    theme: {
        container: {
            screens: containerScreens
        }
    }
},
```

Here it is in the Tailwind Play app as a working example: https://play.tailwindcss.com/0ErQ9yGQvs?size=2142x720&file=config